# How can I dismiss puplet messages with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, redhat-enterprise-linux

puplet is forever reminding me when it's time to run "yum update", which is fine, but I'm forced to click the little x to dismiss the dialog.  Is there a keyboard shortcut or command that can dismiss it for me?  I'm running GNOME 2.16.0 on RHEL5.  Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a timeout means I don't have to dismiss the puplet message:

```
[root@beamish ~]# diff -u /usr/bin/puplet.orig /usr/bin/puplet
--- /usr/bin/puplet.orig        2010-01-07 00:39:09.000000000 -0500
+++ /usr/bin/puplet     2010-07-01 17:06:17.000000000 -0400
@@ -232,7 +232,7 @@
         return len(upds.keys())

     def _showNotify(self, notify, urgency = pynotify.URGENCY_NORMAL,
-                    timeout = 0):
+                    timeout = 1000):
         if self.notify is not None:
             self.notify.close()
         notify.attach_to_status_icon(self.trayicon)
[root@beamish ~]#
```